# Vega Lite: symlog scale with more tick marks

Tags: vega-lite, vega

Is there a way to use the symlog scale, but with tick marks placed on many orders of magnitude?

To explain, the **log** scale has tick marks on many orders of magnitude, but cannot show ≤ 1 values (last bar is hidden in this example):

[image]

On the other hand, **symlog** scale can represent negative, zero, and one-valued data, but by default only has tick marks for the largest order of magnitude:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a list of desired tick values using the `axis.values` specification. For example:

```json
{
  "mark": "point",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 1},
      {"x": 1, "y": 10},
      {"x": 2, "y": 100},
      {"x": 3, "y": 1000},
      {"x": 4, "y": 10000},
      {"x": 5, "y": 100000},
      {"x": 6, "y": 1000000},
      {"x": 7, "y": 10000000}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {
      "field": "y",
      "axis": {"values": [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]},
      "scale": {"type": "symlog", "constant": 1}
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot specify values manually, because I don't know beforehand the magnitude of the data. I should send a bug report to vega lite, I suppose.